Add number of List of references in the table of content
I have a table of contents with the numbers of sections  (as in the picture) and I want to add the "LITERATÚRA" (it ist List of references) as a number 6 and "ZOZNAM POUŽITÝCH SKRATIEK" as a number 7 to the table of contents. I have List of references in bib file.
When I use package \usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}, it adds the number but it is not written as "LITERATÚRA" but "Literatúra" and I want to have it in big letters. How can I rewrite it?
Please heelp.
Here is my document preambule
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
%\usepackage{babelbib}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{epsfig,wrapfig}
%\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{makecell}
%\usepackage[noadjust]{cite} % zkracuje citace do formátu [1-3]
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{diagbox}

%predefinovani mezer v prostredi enumerate, itemize a description
\let\oldenumerate\enumerate
\renewcommand{\enumerate}{
  \oldenumerate
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}}

\let\olditemize\itemize
\renewcommand{\itemize}{
  \olditemize
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}}

  \let\olddescription\description
\renewcommand{\description}{
  \olddescription
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}}

\pagestyle{plain}

\newlength{\defbaselineskip} \setlength{\defbaselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\setlinespacing}[1]%
{\setlength{\baselineskip}{#1 \defbaselineskip}}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{table}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

   %DOKUMENT
\begin{document}
\def\figurename{Obr.}
\def\tablename{Tab.}
\setlinespacing{1.5}
    %\includepdf[pages={1}]{Vstupni_listy/titulni-strana.pdf}
    %\includepdf[pages={2}]{Vstupni_listy/titulni-strana.pdf}
    %\includepdf[pages={3}]{Vstupni_listy/vstupnilisty.pdf}
    %\includepdf[pages={4}]{Vstupni_listy/vstupnilisty.pdf}
    %\includepdf[pages={5}]{Vstupni_listy/vstupnilisty.pdf}
    \include{texty/diky} %zahrnie podakovanie
    \include{texty/souhrn} %zahrnie suhrn
    
    
    
\thispagestyle{empty} %obsah 
\setcounter{page}{0} %obsah
    \tableofcontents %obsah
\thispagestyle{empty} %obsah
\newpage 
\setlinespacing{1.5} 
\setcounter{page}{1}
    \include{texty/uvod}
    \include{texty/teorie}
    %\include{texty/materialy}
    \include{texty/vysledky}
    \include{texty/experiment}
    \include{texty/zaver}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{ZOZNAM SYMBOLOV}
%\include{texty/symboly}


 \setlinespacing{1.5}

\renewcommand{\refname}{LITERATÚRA}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{LITERATÚRA}
\addto{\captionsslovak}{\renewcommand{\bibname}{List of References}}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliographystyle{achemso}
%\selectlanguage{czech}
\bibliography{literatura}
%\include{seznam_literatura}
 \appendix
 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{ZOZNAM POUŽITÝCH SKRATIEK}
\include{texty/zkratky}
    %\include{texty/priloha1}
\end{document}


Off-topic: tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm may be expressed more simply as margin=25mm. Also, is \usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc} for real? I suggest you drop this instruction or, at the very least, replace it with \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}.

Since your test document contains quite a few \include directives, the only person who can compile the test document is you. Please simplify and streamline your test document to make it compilable by others.
